# Error in Module LteMacEndRealisticD2D : out_of_range vector

Tags: omnet++, veins, veins-lte

I am simulating D2D scenario within CAR simulation example of simuLTE. 
I am trying to explore the CAR example under SIMULATION folder by varying the number of vehicles for VoIP D2D network configuration.
The default CAR example works for 10 UEs(or vehicles) but I want to run the same example with 20 vehicles so I generated random trips for the previous used heterogeneous.net.xml. 
Similarly, the changes I made in the configuration in .ini file are as follows:

```
LTE specific parameters
AMC module parameters
**.numUe = ${numUEs=20}
[config VoIP-D2D]
*.car[*].numUdpApps =1
*.car[0..9].udpApp[0].typename = "VoIPSender"
*.car[0..9].udpApp[0].destAddress =  "car["+string(ancestorIndex(1)+10)+"]"
*.car[10..19].udpApp[0].type="VoIPReceiver" 
*.car[0..9].lteNic.d2dPeerAddresses = "car["+string(ancestorIndex(1)+10)+"]"
```

Error encountered :

```
Event #642905  t=20.067  Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D, id=151)  on selfmsg ttiTick_ (omnetpp::cMessage, id=1000872)
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: -----MACRO ENB MAIN LOOP -----
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: H-ARQ RX: feedback sent to TX process 5 Codeword  0of node with id 1027 result: ACK
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: LteMacBase : Sending packet  on port MAC_to_PHY
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: LteHarqBufferRx::extractCorrectPdus H-ARQ RX: pdu (id 1335034 ) extracted from process 5to be sent upper
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: LteBsrBuffers : Added new BSR buffer for node: 1027 for Lcid: 1 Current BSR size: 71
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: LteSchedulerEnb::backlog - backlogged data for Logical Cid 67305473
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067LteMaxCI::notify CID notified 67305473
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: ============================================== UPLINK ==============================================
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067LteSchedulerEnbUl::updateHarqDescs  cell 1
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067LteSchedulerEnbUl::updateHarqDescs UE 1025 OLD Current Process is  0
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067LteSchedulerEnbUl::updateHarqDescs UE 1025NEW Current Process is 1(total harq processes 8)
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067LteSchedulerEnbUl::updateHarqDescs UE 1026 OLD Current Process is  0
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067LteSchedulerEnbUl::updateHarqDescs UE 1026NEW Current Process is 1(total harq processes 8)
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067LteSchedulerEnbUl::updateHarqDescs UE 1027 OLD Current Process is  1
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067LteSchedulerEnbUl::updateHarqDescs UE 1027NEW Current Process is 2(total harq processes 8)
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067LteSchedulerEnbUl::updateHarqDescs UE 1028 OLD Current Process is  0
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067LteSchedulerEnbUl::updateHarqDescs UE 1028NEW Current Process is 1(total harq processes 8)
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067LteSchedulerEnbUl::updateHarqDescs UE 1030 OLD Current Process is  0
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067LteSchedulerEnbUl::updateHarqDescs UE 1030NEW Current Process is 1(total harq processes 8)
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067LteSchedulerEnbUl::updateHarqDescs UE 1032 OLD Current Process is  0
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067LteSchedulerEnbUl::updateHarqDescs UE 1032NEW Current Process is 1(total harq processes 8)
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: LteSchedulerEnb::schedule performed by Node: 1
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteAmc::cleanAmcStructures. Direction UL
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: ___________________________start RTX __________________________________
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteSchedulerEnbUl::racschedule --------------------::[ START RAC-SCHEDULE ]::--------------------
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteSchedulerEnbUl::racschedule eNodeB: 1
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteSchedulerEnbUl::racschedule Direction: UL
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteSchedulerEnbUl::racschedule --------------------::[  END RAC-SCHEDULE  ]::--------------------
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteAllocationModule::computeTotalRbs UL - total 25, allocated 0, 25 blocks available
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteSchedulerEnbUl::rtxschedule --------------------::[ START RTX-SCHEDULE ]::--------------------
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteSchedulerEnbUl::rtxschedule eNodeB: 1
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteSchedulerEnbUl::rtxschedule Direction: UL
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteAllocationModule::computeTotalRbs UL - total 25, allocated 0, 25 blocks available
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteSchedulerEnbUl::rtxschedule residual OFDM Space: 25
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteSchedulerEnbUl::rtxschedule --------------------::[  END RTX-SCHEDULE  ]::--------------------
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: ____________________________ end RTX __________________________________
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: ___________________________start SCHED ________________________________
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteMaxCI::schedule 1
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteAmc::computeTxParams --------------::[ START ]::--------------
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteAmc::computeTxParams CellId: 1
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteAmc::computeTxParams NodeId: 1025
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteAmc::computeTxParams Direction: D2D
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteAmc::computeTxParams - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteAmc::computeTxParams RB allocation type: localized
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteAmc::computeTxParams - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams for UE 1025, direction D2D
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams     LteSummaryFeedback
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams CellId: 0
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams NodeId: 1025
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams Direction: D2D
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams TxMode: TRANSMIT_DIVERSITY
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams -------------------------
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams RI = 1 [1]
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams CQI[0] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0} [{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}]
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams PMI = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} [{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}]
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams NEW values assigned! - CQI =0
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams --------------------------
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams         UserTxParams
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams --------------------------
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams TxMode: TRANSMIT_DIVERSITY
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams RI: 1
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams CQI = {0}
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams PMI: 1
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams Bands = {0}
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams --------------------------
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteAmc::setTxParams DAS antenna set for user 1025 is     [MACRO]
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteAmc::computeTxParams --------------::[  END  ]::--------------
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteAmc::computeTxParams --------------::[ START ]::--------------
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteAmc::computeTxParams CellId: 1
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteAmc::computeTxParams NodeId: 1027
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteAmc::computeTxParams Direction: D2D
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteAmc::computeTxParams - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteAmc::computeTxParams RB allocation type: localized
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 LteAmc::computeTxParams - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
INFO (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D)Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac: 20.067 AmcPilotD2D::computeTxParams for UE 1027, direction D2D
<!> std::out_of_range: vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 14) >= this->size() (which is 1) -- in module (LteMacEnbRealisticD2D) Highway.eNodeB1.lteNic.mac (id=151), at t=20.067s, event #642905
```

Is there any simulation setting I am missing out on?
What is the reason LTE summary feedback is not available for this UE 1027?
If any other details are required, kindly comment. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

BR,
Aman

Comment: Why is this tagged "Veins"? Also, which software versions are you using?

Comment: @ChristophSommer I tagged Veins because Veins is integrated into simuLTE when installing in order to simulate cellular communication in a vehicular network.
S/w versions are : 
Ubuntu 16.04
OMNeT++ v5.1.1;
INET-Framework v3.6;
SUMO v0.30.0